# How to convert Magento 1.9 extension into Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

Is any tools/scripts that can convert magento 1.9 version to magento 2. version?

I need it for magento 2.2.3 community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x have totally different folder structure and coding pattern.**

one can not use Magento 1.x modules directly into Magento 2.x, but there is an official code migration tool which can help the developers to migrate theirs modules and design themes.

The official **[code migration tool](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)** can only assist you to migrate a custom Magento 1.x extension to Magento 2 by doing some part of work automatically.

I never used the tool for my extensions, because an automatical code generation has (almost always) a lower quality then a hand-written, and I preferred to re-think the Magento 2 architecture and to write the code by myself.

**More References**

1. https://www.netsolutions.com/insights/how-to-migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/
2. https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2
3. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

Comment: @alaminmishu if solution work for you then mark as accepted which will help future readers.

Comment: Can I get your skype ID?

Comment: you can mail, https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/63138/aditya-shah?tab=profile